# Unable to load data from csv file to MySQL table using Python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, csv

I wrote the following code for dumping a large data of earthquake records which are in a .csv file into a mysql table using python:

```
import MySQLdb
import os
import string

db = MySQLdb.connect (host="111.100."123.134",port=3306,user="root",\
                  passwd="****",db="mydb")
print "\nConnction to DB established\n"
cursor=db.cursor()

sql = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'all_week.csv' \
     INTO TABLE Eq_records \
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' \
     OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  \
     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' \
     IGNORE 1 LINES;;"""

try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
    print "Data loading complete.\n"
except:
    print "Error in loading data\n"
```

This code is executing fine but the table `Eq_records` in the mysql workbench is empty. Please let me know a solution to this.

Comment: using 'except:' is bad practice and could be hiding the problem. remove the try / except surrounding the cursor and commit, and see if there is a difference.

Comment: You mean to say its correctly printing "Data loading complete.\n" ?

Comment: You might try using an absolute path to your csv file

Answer (score 0):

I executed the same code and got the data into MySQL table. I just disconnected the client connection and connected it back again and refreshed the db and it worked.